# MVVM modeling question for a LOB scenario

Tags: mvvm

I've gone through a lot of intro-level tutorials on MVVM and can certainly see its merits but I'm having a hard time applying it to my LOB application. I plan on using MVVM Light, though I don't think that's going to impact the overall design structure of my VMs.

Suppose I want to write a TaxiDispatcher application where I have a service that goes out every minute and fetches the latest status of each of my taxis. I also have a list of fixed locations that people can call from and request a taxi. The dispatcher would then assign an available taxi to that location. At any given time, each taxi would either be available to the dispatcher or assigned to one of the particular locations in order to pick up a customer.

My main screen (let's call it DispatcherView) would consist of a list of available taxis on the left-side of the screen and then two additional pieces of visual content: a list of my locations (whether or not a person is there requesting service, which taxi has been assigned to that location, etc..) and a list of taxi assignments (elapsed time since they've been assigned, location, etc..).

All 3 of those views work off the same 2 sources: the taxi data service and the list of my locations that I can dispatch a taxi to. Right now, I've got separate views and view models for each of the 3 views (UnassignedTaxisVM, DispatchLocationsVM and AssignedTaxisVM), each being injected with one, or both, of the data sources. When the dispatcher assigns a taxi from the unassigned list, I use a Messenger to communicate with the other VMs to let them know that the taxi has been assigned to a location (the DispatchLocationsView and AssignedTaxisView are both updated with this new information as a result). But when I'm wiring up each VM, I'm having to inject the same datasource(s) to each of my VMs and thus having to write similar code in each VM to respond to the command when the dispatcher assigns a taxi to a location. It may just be my lack of experience with the framework but it just smells bad to me.

Does it make more sense to simply have one VM (DispatcherVM), and have the DispatcherView be responsible for rendering all 3 pieces of visual content? I envision this would involve having 3 ObservableCollections (UnassignedTaxis, Locations, AssignedTaxis) in my DispatcherVM and binding the datasource of each of the sub-views. As new data comes in from my taxi data service, I'd parse/update to the appropriate ObservableCollection and have my views respond that way.

What's the best practice here? I've got 3 distinct, but similar, "views" of the same underlying data. Should I create seperate VMs for each of the views or have one VM expose a view that essnentially consists of 3 separate lists/datagrids, etc..?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have reusable plumbing across ViewModels. Have you considered using inheritance (i.g. a ViewModelBase class) to reuse that plumbing? If inheritance isn't right for your solution, you could go the route of one main VM that is composed of child ViewModels that the main ViewModel coordinates.

Both patterns are equally good solutions at a high level in my opinion. It's hard to know which is more appropriate without a lot of context.